# QGIS 3 3D Marker

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, markers, 3d-map

In the 3D view adding 3d `.obj` files as Markers works very well.
Is it possible to add different 3D markers on different layers or categories?

When I use 2 different layers with different obj files 3D view shows only the first layer symbols.